# Importing live streaming Eclipse project in Android Studio

Tags: android

Well, I did quite a lot study on importing eclipse project to android studio with libraries.But, could not find a solution for my problem. I had started a project of live streaming in eclipse last year and want to move it to android studio.I tried it with lot of different ideas but yet not could fix it. I have used libstreaming library previously and want to use the same again. Please suggest me what I need to do for it.I get this error.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':libstreaming:processReleaseResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/home/developer/Desktop/android-sdk-linux/24.0.0/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```